# Brackets-like Quick Edit feature for Visual Studio Code

Tags: edit

Brackets editor (and Dreamweaver too) from Adobe has a feature called Quick Edit which allows inline modification in the related pieces of code across various files without opening those files in a separate tab. Moreover, if you created a class for the tag, but did not describe it in CSS, then Quick Edit will prompt you to create a new rule with this class. This feature seems very handy and it will be nice to have in VSC as well. Whether there is such feature
in VSC?

You can see a screenshot here:
https://discourse-cdn-sjc1.com/business6/uploads/github_atom/114/9b11a0df3ac8c756.jpg

Answer (score 4):

There is a [Peek](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_peek) feature that looks like what you are looking for.

You can use it by pressing Alt + F12 (Option + F12 on macOS, Ctrl + Shift + F10 on Linux).

Since you need it for CSS, you need to install [this plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pranaygp.vscode-css-peek) for Peek.